# How to specify the prior statement in MCMCglmm in R?

Tags: r

I am currently working on a random intercept logistic regression with the MCMCglmm package. I have specified:

```
mcmc <- MCMCglmm(Event ~ 1+Wind+Humidity, random = ~Engineer, data=spares.data, 
    family="categorical",nitt=20000,burnin=3000, thin=24,prior=list(R=list(V=1, fix=1), G=list(G1=list(V=1, nu=0.002))),pr=T,pl=T)
```

My question now is:

Does the specification of

```
prior=list(R=list(V=1, fix=1), G=list(G1=list(V=1, nu=0.002)))
```

give me the following (mathematical) specification of the prior distributions:

beta_0, beta_1, beta_2 ~ Normal(0,10^10)

tau^2 ~ InvGamma(0.001,0.001)

Thanks in advance :-)